# How to make two level select option category and subcategory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help with the following:

How to make two level select option. `category` and `subcategory` with JavaScript?

```
<select id="category" required>
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option class="Volvo" value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option class="Saab" value="2">Saab</option>
    <option class="Opel" value="3">Opel</option>
    <option class="Audi" value="4">Audi</option>
</select> 
 <select id="subcategory">
  <optgroup class="Volvo" required>
  <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="44">XC60</option>
    <option value="55">XC90</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="Saab" required>
  <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="66">Saab 9XX</option>
    <option value="77">Saab Aero-X</option>
  </optgroup>
   <optgroup class="Opel" required>
   <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="88">Corsa A</option>
    <option value="99">Corsa B</option>
  </optgroup>
   <optgroup class="Audi" required>
   <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="616">Audi A4</option>
    <option value="717">Audi A8</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

I need make two level select option with javascript or jquery I don't know how JavaScript works and I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#subcategory').find('optgroup').hide(); // initialize
$('#category').change(function() {
    var $cat = $(this).find('option:selected');
    var $subCat = $('#subcategory').find('.' + $cat.attr('class'));
    $('#subcategory').find('optgroup').not("'" + '.' + $cat.attr('class') + "'").hide(); // hide other optgroup
    $subCat.show();
    $subCat.find('option').first().attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

[**Online demo(jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/e3ysk26b/3/)

Comment: one more question how to make the subcategory required and first class must be seen <option value="" selected>select model type</option>

Comment: how to make subcategory required  ? can you help me fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Two Level selectoption AKA Multilevel dropdowns can designed using HTML,CSS.

Based on the functional requirements, Javascript can be used for implementing additional features in Multilevel dropdowns.

Multilevel dropdowns can be designed by making use of `<div> tags` or `<ul> tags` .

i Personally prefer `<ul> tags`

Take a look at my codepen (https://codepen.io/Divine1/pen/mXVPmQ) to have an understanding on how to start designing multi-level dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('category');
el.onchange = function(){
 var category = $('#category :selected').attr('class');
  $('#subcategory optgroup').hide();
  $('#subcategory').val("");
  $('#subcategory .'+category).show();
}
```

```css
#subcategory optgroup{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="category" required>
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option class="Volvo" value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option class="Saab" value="2">Saab</option>
    <option class="Opel" value="3">Opel</option>
    <option class="Audi" value="4">Audi</option>
</select> 
 <select id="subcategory">
  <optgroup class="Volvo" required>
  <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="44">XC60</option>
    <option value="55">XC90</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="Saab" required>
  <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="66">Saab 9XX</option>
    <option value="77">Saab Aero-X</option>
  </optgroup>
   <optgroup class="Opel" required>
   <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="88">Corsa A</option>
    <option value="99">Corsa B</option>
  </optgroup>
   <optgroup class="Audi" required>
   <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="616">Audi A4</option>
    <option value="717">Audi A8</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```